# Jboss 7.1 standalone socket/port error

Tags: java, macos, sockets, jboss, jboss7.x

System: OS X 10.7.X

When starting jboss from the terminal I get a bind exception without a port number being mentioned. Could anyone enlighten me?

```
11:52:27,635 ERROR [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol] (MSC service thread 1-11) Error initializing endpoint: java.lang.Exception: Socket bind failed: [48] Address already in use
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.init(AprEndpoint.java:578) [jbossweb-7.0.7.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol.init(Http11AprProtocol.java:121) [jbossweb-7.0.7.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.init(Connector.java:983) [jbossweb-7.0.7.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.as.web.WebConnectorService.start(WebConnectorService.java:267) [jboss-as-web-7.1.0.CR1b.jar:7.1.0.CR1b]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1824) [jboss-msc-1.0.1.GA.jar:1.0.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1759) [jboss-msc-1.0.1.GA.jar:1.0.1.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [:1.6.0_29]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [:1.6.0_29]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [:1.6.0_29]

11:52:27,637 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-11) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.web.connector.http: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.connector.http: LifecycleException:  Protocol handler initialization failed: java.lang.Exception: Socket bind failed: [48] Address already in use
        at org.jboss.as.web.WebConnectorService.start(WebConnectorService.java:271)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1824) [jboss-msc-1.0.1.GA.jar:1.0.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1759) [jboss-msc-1.0.1.GA.jar:1.0.1.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [:1.6.0_29]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [:1.6.0_29]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [:1.6.0_29]
Caused by: LifecycleException:  Protocol handler initialization failed: java.lang.Exception: Socket bind failed: [48] Address already in use
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.init(Connector.java:985)
        at org.jboss.as.web.WebConnectorService.start(WebConnectorService.java:267)
        ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in standalone.xml, there should be a section at the end with port numbers (from what i remember!). You could just check to see if any other process is using any of them.

More specifically, the stacktrace names the web connector, which should help narrow down which port this is. I would expect it to be the main HTTP port, which i think is 8080 by default.

It is really, really annoying that the exception doesn't specify the port.

Comment: Just to let everyone know, the issue was a http-proxy service which installed by the latest release of avast for mac. I had to use "nmap" to find the missing link because the "lsof" command did not not find the service locking the port ... .

Comment: `netstat -a -f inet -n`, on OS X, should also show the service on the port. I'd be interested to hear if it doesn't; i'm not sure how reliable it is on OS X.